# How to apply a function on combining two columns in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns "**ColA**" and "**ColB**" in a pandas dataframe like below:

[image]

I want apply a custom function on **ColA** and **ColB**, and update another column **ColC**. The custom function is like below:

```
def customFunc(file_name, pattern):
    match_index = -1
    with open(file_name) as f:
      data = f.read()
      for n, line in enumerate(data):
        match_index = line.find(pattern)
        if match_index != -1:
          break

    return match_index
```

For each row of the dataframe, the **file_name** will come from **ColA** and **pattern** will come from **ColB** and the returned **match_index** will be updated in **ColC** like below:

[image]

I have tried like below but the value of ColA and ColB of each row is not passed into the custom function.

```
df["ColC"] = df[["ColA", "ColB"]].apply(lambda x: customFunc(x.ColA, x.ColB))
```

How to pass ColA and ColB of each row into the custom function using apply()?

Comment: You need to apply with axis=1.  df.apply(...., axis-1)

Answer (score 0):

using **axis = 1** did the trick.

```
df["ColC"] = df[["ColA", "ColB"]].apply(lambda x: customFunc(x.ColA, x.ColB), axis = 1)
```